# 2.81 Smooth shading not working with normal map

Tags: shaders

I am just testing this out with a regular UV sphere and a noise texture. I'm seeing  hard cornered of the mesh (like flat shading)what am I doing wrong?

[image].

[image]

Comment: Have you enabled *Auto-smooth* under *Object Properties*?

Comment: Tried it. Doesn't make a difference.